# Input.IsKeyDown не реагирует на нажатие клавиши

Tags: sfml, видео, c++, linux

Использую библиотеку SFML.

```
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow app(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "test");
    bool running = true;
    while(running)
    {
        std::cout << app.GetInput().IsKeyDown(sf::Key::Left) << "\n";
    }
    app.Display();
    return 0;
```

}

Сколько бы я не давил на кнопку влево, на экране появляется только 0. Окно в фокусе. В чем причина? OC - Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что же, пришло время ответить на свой вопрос. Сколько бы разработчики не заявляли о "realtime input", получать события нужно все равно. Поэтому, прежде чем использовать методы IsKeyDown и ему подобные, надо события получить. То есть, в данном случае, внутрь цикла до вызова метода надо дописать следующее:
sf::Event Event;
app.GetEvent(Event);
Вот и все.